# netbeans debug two projects at same time

Tags: debugging, netbeans-7

I´m try debug two projects at same time in Netbeans and I'm having some problems. One project call the other. In the first I start this with debug mode. In the second I put some breakpoints. The process stop in the breakpoint but when click in the button to go to next step this go for the next breakpoint (if have) or execute the code at the final..

The question is: what do for netbeans go to next step in this case?

I using netbeans 7.2 on Windows 7 and debugging Java code using jdk1.6.0_24.

Answer (score 3):

You can start debugging of as much projects as you want concurrently. 
Look then into Window/Debugging/Sessions, which will open a view with 
all running sessions, you can also change the current one in that view.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 8 should support this out-of-the-box and generate a new jpda.address port for each app.

If not, you have a few options to do this:

1. Run multiple instances of NetBeans (Makes sure the 'userdir' is different for both).

2. Specify a different `jpda.address=<port>` for one of the applications. You can add this in `Project Properties` > `Actions` > `Debug` > `Set Properties`.